# How to use external file to handle push notifications in FirefoxOS?

Tags: push, message, firefox-os

I'm trying to get working Push Notifications on my FirefoxOS App. While it's working as expecte when the app is opened, when the app is closed it not works anymore. I thought that was the app is trying to execute the whole app instead only the handler so I'm trying to use the messages section on the manifest.webapp.

```
"messages": [
    { "push": "/push/push.html" },
    { "push-register" : "index.html" },
    { "notification": "index.html" }
],
```

My code on /push/push.html is:

```
<script>

navigator.mozSetMessageHandler('push', function () {
  c = new Notification( 'testing 4' );
});
</script>
```

But it seems that's not loading the file when the push message arrives the device. For me, it doesn't seems to be a path problem, because I tried everything (launch path is /index.html, and I've tried moving push.html to the root and put /push.html).

Any clue?

Comment: Does the manifest have a `permissions: push` field? Have you registered your app to the endpoint? Did you tried to put a debug message in push.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after hours trying it and a lot of research, seems that's not possible to get working the push in another page.

> Remember: when a user selects an app, the lauch_path is displayed.
> There’s a bug right now that restricts push notifications to the page
> that calls register(). Right now, what’s under “messages” doesn’t
> matter if it’s not the same as the page that calls register(). Keep
> your eye on that bug if you want to know when it’s fixed. For now,
> it’s probably a good idea to keep your app to one page and use dynamic
> formatting to present info back to the user.
>
> Firefox OS v1.1 only allows the page that registers for Push
> Notifications to recieve them, so you cannot have / call
> navigator.push.register() and have /push.html be the receiver that
> uses navigator.mozSetMessageHandler().

More info about the bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=800431 [^]
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=897112 [^]